# How to fix ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive

Tags: angular

I have this line in my angular project:

```
 <option *ngFor="let item of painLevels" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.painlevel}}</option>
```

and I am getting this error:

> ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent
>   formGroup directive.  Try using
>         formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead.

How would I apply [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" to a dropdown menu? All I see is examples for inputs. Or is there a better way to fix this?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel

Comment: Yes, but how would I apply this to a select?

Answer (score 1):

you can use like that my example below;

```
<select name="country" formControlName="country" id="country" class="form-control form-control-element" [(ngModel)]="country">
  <option value="90">Turkey</option>
  <option value="1">USA</option>
  <option value="30">Greece</option>
</select>
```

do not forget to use `formControlName="country"`

and do not forget to read that update note from angular.io

> Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with 
>       reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed 
>       in Angular v7.

Comment: name="country"
formControlName="country"
[(ngModel)]="country"

3 things that I was looking for thanks

Answer (score 1):

```html
<select name="country" formControlName="country" id="country" 
       class="formcontrol form-control-element" [(ngModel)]="country">
   <option value="90">Turkey</option>
   <option value="1">USA</option>
   <option value="30">Greece</option>
</select>
```

```html
name="country"
formControlName="country" 
[(ngModel)]="country"
```

Those are the three things need to use ngModel inside a formGroup directive.

Note that same name should be used.